# Azure continuous deployment issue when using Node.js and Github

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-2013

Azure allows you to deploy from source code located in Github. I've been able to create my first Node app in Visual Studio but when trying to set up continuous deployment (meaning that whenever I push changes to the github repository, it automatically publishes to my azure website), I won't update. My azure portal shows that commits have been made and updates the deployments, but the website won't show the actual changes. What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: First step is to identify if it's a runtime or deployment issue. See https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-vs-runtime-issues

Comment: Was a deployment issue, and very dumb one. Can't believe it took me so long to figure it out. Thanks!